# How to convert mixed map string back to mixed map in Java

Tags: java

I have a mixed map like: `private Map<Integer, Map<Character, Float>> probabilities = new HashMap<>();`

And the output for that as string is: `this.probabilities.toString() => {0={a=0.5}, 1={s=0.75}, 2={�=1.0}}`

So is there I way to convert this output to mixed map as before?

Keep in mind that I can have any type of Character like "}" that could end up looking like:

`{0={a=0.25}, 1={"=0.5}, 2={s=0.625}, 3={{=0.75}, 4={�=0.875}, 5={}=1.0}}`

Comment: Are you asking to reading the `toString` of your map object and get back a a `Map.class`? without using existing `parsing` libraries available like jackson or gson which can read a json String?

Comment: Correct, I mean I could probably split the string up several times with = and {} but what if those are characters. I would need to put the map in string in a different format especially because any char can  be used so I would need to join values by double char like ++ and then to split by ++ because char can only be one. So before doing that I was thinking if there is .toString() option  on map maybe there is some reverse as well.

Comment: Or wrong, I would need to split with two or more chars that are different like =>

Comment: Yes you would need to verify and write logic on a for loop across multiple conditions mostly specific to your character types. What have you done so far?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to to that. Now read: [Why is “Is there a way to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: But why? Why do you need to write it out in that format in the first place (as opposed to something more standard and accessible like JSON/XML/YAML/... )?

Comment: Probably because I wanted to make it look unaccessible :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method for parsing that string back into your nested map.

```
static Map<Integer, Map<Character, Float>> parse(String input) {
    if (! input.startsWith("{") || ! input.endsWith("}"))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input (missing surrounding '{}'): " + input);
    Map<Integer, Map<Character, Float>> output = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\G(\\d+)=\\{(.)=([0-9.]+)\\}(?:, |$)")
            .matcher(input).region(1, input.length() - 1);
    int end = 1;
    while (m.find()) {
        output.computeIfAbsent(Integer.valueOf(m.group(1)), k -> new LinkedHashMap<>())
                .put(m.group(2).charAt(0), Float.valueOf(m.group(3)));
        end = m.end();
    }
    if (end != input.length() - 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input at: " + input.substring(end));
    return output;
}
```

*Test*

```
Map<Integer, Map<Character, Float>> probabilities = new TreeMap<>(Map.of(
        0, Map.of('a', 0.25f),
        1, Map.of('"', 0.5f),
        2, Map.of('s', 0.625f),
        3, Map.of('{', 0.75f),
        4, Map.of('�', 0.875f),
        5, Map.of('}', 1.0f)
));
System.out.println("probabilities = " + probabilities);

String input = "{0={a=0.25}, 1={\"=0.5}, 2={s=0.625}, 3={{=0.75}, 4={�=0.875}, 5={}=1.0}}";
System.out.println("input         = " + input);

Map<Integer, Map<Character, Float>> output = parse(input);
System.out.println("output        = " + output);
```

*Output*

```
probabilities = {0={a=0.25}, 1={"=0.5}, 2={s=0.625}, 3={{=0.75}, 4={�=0.875}, 5={}=1.0}}
input         = {0={a=0.25}, 1={"=0.5}, 2={s=0.625}, 3={{=0.75}, 4={�=0.875}, 5={}=1.0}}
output        = {0={a=0.25}, 1={"=0.5}, 2={s=0.625}, 3={{=0.75}, 4={�=0.875}, 5={}=1.0}}
```

Comment: Thank you buddy, I looped through the map and make string like:
`0=>s<>0.25<=1=>t<>0.75<=2=>e<>1.0<=` and then split string by <=, then by => and at the end by <> which worked as well. But your answer is better